# jquery using multiple selectors in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I came across a strange situation. 
I have recently looked more into jquery and have updated some of my old code.

instead of having onClick inside a html tag I changed it to

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#top_menu, :button, .big').on('click', 
            function () {
                window.open($(this).data('link'), '_self', ''); 
            }
        );
    }
);
```

And the IE didn't redirect on mouse click. Instead if went to the address `http://mylocaladdress/mysubdir/undefined`

After a lot of frustration and playing around i changed the 
`$('#top_menu, :button, .big')` to `$('#top_menu :button, .big')` and it worked like a charm.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: whether the buttons are in the `#top_menu` element? the problem could be because of event propagation

Comment: @ArunPJohny it may be, but how did the first one become not working while the second one works..?

Comment: For `#top_menu`, `$(this).data('link')` will return undefined, i presume

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy because `#top_menu` may not have the data property `link`

Comment: Its complete guess work before actually seeing HTML. Can you post some relevant HTML?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (multiple, selectors) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:S 
complete rookie mistake. 
During the code change I for some reason had lost the id form the menu table

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing = "0" id="#top_menu">
           <tr>
            <td><button class="big" style="font-weight: bold;" nowrap data-link="[action]">[name]</button></td>
...
           </tr>
    </table>
```

Sorry for the trouble.

Actually the funny thing about it is that it worked just fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with `$(this).data('link')` so please try with `$(this).attr('data-link')` instead of `$(this).data('link')`

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#top_menu, :button, .big').on('click', 
            function () {
                window.open($(this).attr('data-link'), '_self', ''); 
            }
        );
    }
);
```